# Hibernate - Perform HQL query on Criteria Result

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, criteria

I am concerned with a problem regarding criteria and hql.
In first step a complex criteria construction limits a big amount of datasets.
In second step a hql calculation should be performed on these preselected datasets of step one.

The problem is that the code of both has been developed seperately and i am wondering if it is possible to just perform the hql query as a subquery on the result of the first limitation of data. Both calculations should be performed on database level because it is a big amount of data.

I would be very happy for any help or advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible to just perform the hql query as a subquery on the result of the first limitation of data.

To my knowledge, there is nothing like that in the API.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Then i probably have to convert the code.